# mysql derived table in where clause for derived table

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework

I have some SQL (cut down  from Entity Framework for readabilty) that works in SQL Server but not MySQL.  I am assuming this means I have hit a limitation of MySQL but can not be sure.

I have 3 tables:

products with a ProductId and AccommodationId

accommodations with an AccommodationId

rooms with a RoomId

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM products) AS Project1
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT *
  FROM rooms
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM accommodations AS A  WHERE Project1.AccommodationId = A.AccommodationId)
    AS Project2 ON 1 = 1
  )
```

I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Project1.AccommodationId' in 'where clause'
```

I would like to understand this error to see if I can change my code to get EntityFramework to produce compatible SQL.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot JOIN to a subquery in MYSQL and refer back to one of the other tables in your main `FROM` clause.  That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot JOIN to a subquery in MYSQL and refer back to one of the other tables in your main FROM clause. That won't work.

Wow, that's some really ugly looking code right there.  I think what it boils down to is the following.  It just gets there in a REALLY round about way.

```
SELECT  Project1.*

FROM    products AS Project1

        INNER JOIN accommodations AS A 
        ON Project1.AccommodationId = A.AccommodationId
```

Comment: Hi,

thanks for your answer.  Yes, your SQL is correct for the scenario I described, but the SQL I quoted was highly cut down and doesn't actually solve my real coding problem.  I can understand people liking ORM and all the advantages it gives, but as a SQL developer until these technologies can write accurate betterSQL than me I would rather do it my way.

Thanks for your answer, I'm going to hope I've configured EF wrong for MySQL so tha when done it can produce MySQL compatible SQL.